# Git Parameter Plugin showing all branches list

Tags: git, jenkins

My Git parameter plugin showing all the branches listing in git repository. I need list of branches which are under Dev and master only

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any useful information on the branch parameter plugin. If I had to guess from your screenshots, then I'd think that the branch filter is a pattern to limit the branches to select from.

I would try to provide a regular expression for that parameter. Try for example `(master|DEV/).*`. Most probably the help text of that field will guide you jn the right direction.